# Failed to start tomcat.service after install Tomcat9 by YUM

Tags: linux, daemon, tomcat

I installed tomcat9 on my EC2 server using commands

```
sudo su
yum install tomcat9
```

Then I tried running the command:

```
/usr/sbin/tomcat9 start
```

Then the error message is:

> Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service not found.

Am I missing anything?
What file is tomcat.service? Where do I need to create it? What does it contain?

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service<<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-17
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat9
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/tomcat9
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/share/tomcat9/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M'
ExecStart=/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

However, when I run it, I get an error

```
# /usr/sbin/tomcat9 start
```

> ```
> Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xeu tomcat.service" for details.
> ```

```
# systemctl status tomcat.service
```

> × tomcat.service - Tomcat Server
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-16 16:08:18 JST; 2min 57s ago
> Process: 281460 ExecStart=/usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
> CPU: 621us
>
> ```
>  5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting tomcat.service - Tomcat Server...
>  5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[281460]: tomcat.service: Failed to locate executable
> ```
>
> /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh: No such file or direc>
> 5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[281460]: tomcat.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning
> /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/catalina.sh: No such file or dire>
> 5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited,
> status=203/EXEC
> 5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> 5月 16 16:08:18 ip-172-31-25-139.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start tomcat.service - Tomcat Server.

I checked the directory /usr/share/tomcat9/bin/ and I did not see the file catalina.sh.

Am I missing any steps in my installation?